# Prevent MVC4 SelectList from being 'required'

Tags: validation, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations

I have a SelectList in a Razor page where the user should be able to select an item or not as they see appropriate.

The selected item value is an integer that is a property in an Entity Framework database-first table/class and I have an associated buddy class with the meta data - but there isn't any significant meta data for this value and definitely **not** the *Required* attribute. I only mention it because I've imported System.ComponentModel and System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations and it's possible that might have some bearing on things.

In the Razor page I have:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.blah, MySelectList, "(select)")
```

and the source code for the page reveals:

```
<select data-val="true" data-val-number="The field blah must be a number." data-val-required="The blah field is required." ...>
```

I didn't ask for 'required' but it's there: how do I inhibit it?

Crispin

Answer (score 0):

I think as "blah" is an integer... it is always required.
You need to make blah a nullable int.

Comment: That either means changing the database or putting in an interim variable, neither of which is ideal. I was really just looking for a validation 'off' switch.

Comment: BTW, you should be using ViewModels in your views, not the model itself (the one tied to database). If you were using viewmodels, the change impact is contained.

Comment: I had a go at using jQuery to remove the "data-val" and allied attributes to see if that would help, but the unobtrusive validation attribute additions appear to be kicking in after my $(function() {...}); With respect to view models, I agree. This is an old project and now I would use code-first EF, view models, a healthy dose of knockout.js, etc.  However as a wise person said "never underestimate the value of working code".